# Association one column in model to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, models

Hello i have to model like;

```
class CreateLecturers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :lecturers do |t|
      t.string :firstname
      t.string :lastname
      t.string :position
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and here is my second model.

```
class CreateCurriculums < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :curriculums do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :hours
      t.integer :year
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I want migrate to Curriculums to Lecturer. But not with id, with title
how it's can be possible?

So i use rails-admin. When i add some Curriculum i want to choose with dropdown lecturer and when i add some Lecturer i want to choose Curriculum between models .

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you have to have association between two models. Also do not forget to add `curriculum_id` to `lectures` table.

**curriculum.rb**

```
has_many :lectures
```

**lecture.rb**

```
belongs_to :curriculum
```

**To add migration**

`rails g migration add_curriculum_id_to_lectures curriculum_id:integer`